# I have fetched the data in mvc using MVC data model. But now I am unable to Edit the data though I have created Edit view and parsed in the controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, http-get

I just need the simple code that will enable the edit function in mvc.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Employee_details emp)
{
     var ID = emp.EmployeeId;
     var NAME = emp.Name;
     var Age = emp.Age;
     var Address = emp.Address;
     var Salary = emp.Salary;
     //Add code to update the employee list

     return RedirectToAction("EmpList");
}
```

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Employee_details emp)
        {
            var ID = emp.EmployeeId;
            var NAME = emp.Name;
            var Age = emp.Age;
            var Address = emp.Address;
            var Salary = emp.Salary;
            //Add code to update the employee list
            


            return RedirectToAction("EmpList");
        }

Comment: Visual Studio C# should autogenerate all of this for you. Are you using entity framework? We need to know what data layer you are using to suggest a method to save data

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework, only thing you need is the todo is to call the Save() or Update() Method of the BaseEntity class . i.e Entity.Save() or Entity.Update().